# How to retrieve custom field 3 levels deep from custom metadata

Tags: apex, soql, salesforce-id, casting

I retrieve a field 3 levels deep which is working currently. The field which I currenly retrieve is going to become a dynamic field retrieved from custom metadata. How do I cast this to an id?
I currently have the following but this isnt working:

```
Id conId = (Id) duInv.Invoice__r.BillingAccount__r.(Mdt.AccountContactId__c);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the sObject.get method:

```
Id conId = (Id) duInv.Invoice__r.BillingAccount__r.get(Mdt.AccountContactId__c);
```

Assuming that Mdt is the custom metadata record, and AccountContactId__c is the lookup field.

Comment: Thanks didn't think of that.